# Force rebuild of aggregated css/js

Tags: 8, css-js-aggregation

I have manually removed all aggregated css and js files from sites/default/files.

I would like Drupal to regenerate these, but it does not. Drupal is still looking for the old files, the ones I have deleted.

Clearing the cache does nothing.

How do I force Drupal to recognize that the files are missing and need to be recreated?

Comment: Double check that Drupal is able/has permission and has the correct folder owner/group to write to your folder.

Comment: It definitely does.

Comment: You sure about the `owner/group` part? because you could have the correct 
write `permissions` but if `owner/group` is wrong then you  cannot write. In addition, you could also try unchecking, saving, and then rechecking, saving the [settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7bRRP.jpg)

Comment: This has nothing to do with file or folder permissions. The files were created before by Drupal so it should be able to create them again, but it simply doesn't. Only "drush cr" seems to work, but that refreshes all other caches, which will temporary slow down the whole site.

Comment: With "Clearing the cache does nothing" you mean the browser cache or the Drupal cache. Clearing the latter should definitely work!

Answer (score 0):

In D7 you might want to clear also the variables drupal_js_cache_files and drupal_css_cache_files:

```
drush vdel drupal_js_cache_files && drush vdel drupal_css_cache_files
```

Other than that, do you have any other cache on top of drupal (varnish?). Your pages could be cached with the reference to the old JS files. Is your site broken (404 on CSS/JS files) or is it just referencing the old ones? Usually drupal regenerates aggregated files if it can't find it.

Comment: This is a D8 question.